# return false but still post to next page

Tags: jquery, submit, return, checkbox

I have a group of 3 checkboxes and if non of them checked it will return false and warning message.
When I submit the form, I got warning message that "You must check at least one color!" then the function will return false. However, it will still post to the next page. I suppose it will prompt me to check the checkbox. 
Can someone help me!

```
<FORM ACTION=' ||cur_page||' METHOD="POST" class="myform" id="myform"  >


<p><label>Select color<em>*</em></label><div class="required">
<input type="checkbox" name="p_red" id="p_red" class="require-one" value="RED" /> RED </p>
<p><label>&nbsp;</label><input type="checkbox" name="p_blue" id="p_blue" class="require-one" value="BLUE"  /> BLUE </p>
<p><label>&nbsp;</label><input type="checkbox" name="p_yellow" id="p_yellow" class="require-one" value="YELLOW"  /> YELLOW </P></div>

<div><input type="submit" value="Pay By Credit" name="RTS_Button" class="button red"  ></div>


<SCRIPT>
$(document).ready(function() {     
    $("#myform").submit(function() {         
        var $fields = $(this).find(''input:checkbox[id="p_color"]:checked'');         
        if (!$fields.length) {             
            alert("You must check at least one color!");             
            return false; // The form should *not* submit         
         }     
      }); 
});

</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: Why have you got a non-functional label containing only an `&nbsp;`?

Comment: I want to align the checkboxes on the righ hand side of the screen but not under the label of "Select color *" (which is on the left side)

Answer (score 1):

`.length` return a number
Try this instead:

```
     if ($fields.length === 0) {             
        alert("You must check at least one color!");             
        return false; // The form should *not* submit         
     }
```

Comment: But I have the alert displayed on the screen so I assume the function return false. After I click 'ok' on the message it goes to the next page and do not stay on the same page wait for the enter of the check box.

Comment: I tried if ($fields.length == 0) {  and I got the same result of displaying the message then clink 'ok' then go to next page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
    <form action="javascript:sendForm();">
```

And for your script:

```
    function submitForm() {
        var $fields = $(this).find(''input:checkbox[id="p_color"]:checked'');         
        if (!$fields.length) {             
            alert("You must check at least one color!");             
            return false; // The form won't submit
         }
         else {
             //Run an ajax call from here to POST your data
             alert("Ajax worked (or not), but the fields were checkd");
         }
```

It's a different approach/UX, though.